# Unable to locate anchor element(href) with javascript in webpage in selenium webdriver(chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium

I am pretty much new to selenium. I have referred previous posts and found out how to click an element using javaScriptExecutor. But unfortunately, it is not working and i can;t where I am going wrong. Below is the code snippet and some screenshots:

[This is how i found out the Xpath in chrome:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHomF.png)

Code :

```
    @Test
public void Search(){
    try{

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,\"javascript:__doPostBack('lbSearch','')\")]"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Search element not found."+ e.getStackTrace());
    }
```

[Result :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQhoy.png)

Thankx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `JavaScriptExecuter` you can also click normally by selenium function library.

Your xpath will be `//*[@id='lbSearch']`

You can click using below code,

```
@Test
public void Search(){
     WebElement element = null;
    try{

       element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lbSearch']"));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Search element not found."+ e.getStackTrace());
    }
    element.click();
}
```

One more thing you have to use implicit and explicit wait for locate element. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041341/webdriver-selenium-java-lang-nullpointerexception-while-trying-to-locate-a-webel/35058242#35058242) link will help you.

Comment: Have you initialize your driver properly? Are you getting error? then provide me error log.

Comment: @Sanjay..here is my code...`public String baseUrl = "URL";
 public WebDriver driver;
 
 @BeforeSuite
 public void beforeTestSearch(){
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users/navyatha.devaraju/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS); `

Comment: Script has not issue. Issue is with chromedriver and request-response. Look at this que, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-run-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connection .

Comment: If not works then remove your try-catch block and run your script again, Then provide error log if there is another problem.

Comment: @Sanay...i tried the same code in firefox..i am getting the same error!!

Comment: It is just informational message. After remove try-catch block run your script and show error log for findElement. then let me know.

Comment: @Sanjya...I am getting the same exception message on the console..as in the screenshot.."Search Element not found.."

Comment: It is a locator issue. Make sure your locator is visible before timeout and unique. If timeout occurs then try also Thread.sleep(--) before locating element. Locate with different strategy like class id xpath or even through attribute. Eg, By.xpath("//*a[@class='topMenuLink']") , By.linkText("//*a[@id='Search']") , By.xpath("//*a[contains(@href,'lbSearch')]"). But make sure whatever locator you make , it should be unique and visible.

Comment: FAILED: Search
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(@href,\"javascript:__doPostBack('lbSearch','')\")]"}
Command duration or timeout: 45.11 seconds

Comment: Your xpath syntext is wrong, It should be in this format. //a[contains(@href,'')]. There is no need to enter every character. just enter unique character , it uses contains so it will take it.