# How to use Fluent wait for Listbox WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver. Can anybody help me to use the `fluentwait` in my script?
Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul id="ui-id-6" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" tabindex="0" style="display: block; width: 827px; top: 405px; left: 374px;">
```

Comment: where is your html ?

Comment: <ul id="ui-id-6" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" tabindex="0" style="display: block; width: 827px; top: 405px; left: 374px;">

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("ul#ui-id-6"))));
```

Comment: i had used this code but the problem is when i execute the script first time in the day, script getting failed and org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException is coming every time

Comment: try increasing the time.. to 20

Answer (score 0):

By Using Fluent waits, it waits till the element is found. If the element is not found, it retries every 5 seconds, but will wait only up to a maximum of 30 seconds.

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
   .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
   .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
   .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

Comment: Script unable to select the item from list box by using this wait statement, message "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException" is printed in the console

Answer (score 0):

Use WebDriver wait in try/catch block,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    WebElement ele = null;
    try {
          ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                  .presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    } catch (Exception e) {
          throw e;
    }
```

also need to pass timeout in long.
For more information on dealing with internally as well external wait follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35058242/2838451) answer. :)